# Concat data frames : Adding a name to data frame column which does not have a name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a data frame by concatenating several data frames .The code is given below.

```
summary_FR =pd.concat([Chip_Cur_Summary_funct_mode2,Noise_Summary_funct_mode2,VCM_Summary_funct_mode2,Sens_Summary_funct_mode2,Vbias_Summary_funct_mode2,vcm_delta_Summary_funct_mode2,THD_FUN_M2,F_LOW_FUNC_Summary_mode2,OSC_FUNC_Summary_mode2,FOSC_FUNC_Summary_mode2,VREF_CP_FUNC_Summary_mode2,Summary_PSRR_1KHz_funct_mode2,Summary_PSRR_20Hzto20KHz_funct_mode2])
```

The image of the table is given below. You can see that the 1st column don't have any name.I need to set it name as *Parameter* and make it as unique index column.

I tried the below code to set the name as 'Parameter' and I failed.

```
summary_FR.columns = ["Parameters", "SPEC_MIN", "SPEC_TYP", "SPEC_MAX","min","mean","max","std","Units","Remarks"]
# summary_FR.set_index()
```

May I know where I went wrong.Can someone please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to share the error message but that is probably an index column. You need to call reset_index on the concatenated dataframe like

```
summary_FR =pd.concat([Chip_Cur_,...,Summar]).reset_index()
```

then you can change the colun names.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a name for the index in the following way:

```
your_dataframe.index.name = 'Parameter'
```